# Proving the stability of fixed point

Tags: induction, fixed-point-theorems

How do I prove the following statement :

$$ \forall k \geqslant 1, \ |f^k(x)-p| \leqslant a^k|x-p|$$

inductively? $p$ is a stable fixed point of $f$ and $f'(p) \leqslant a < 1$. $f$ is a continuous and differentiable function.

Let $k = 1$. Then :

$$ |f(x)-p| \leqslant a|x-p|  $$

The mean value theorem says there exists a range $e$ so that the slope of the line, that goes through $p$ and any $x$ in $[p+e,p-e]$ and $x \neq p$ is equal or less than $a$.

Assume $k = n$> Then :

$$|f^n(x)-p| \leqslant a^n|x-p|$$

Let $k = n + 1$

$$|f^n+1(x)-p| \leqslant a^n+1|x-p|  $$

$$RHS = a^n+1|x-p|  
    = a*a^n|x-p| $$

$a|f^n(x)-p|$ is less or equal by the assumption and this is where I get stuck. I've been trying to modify the last expression to all directions to be equal to LHS or larger without really getting anywhere.

Comment: Please write in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use that $p=f(p)$.\begin{align}
|f^{n+1}(x)-p|&=|f(f^n(x))-f(p)|\\
&\le a\,|f^n(x)-p|\\
&\le a^{n+1}|x-p|
\end{align}